# ExtJS how to remove grid row underline when selected and over

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

Hi I have a grid panel and I want to override it.

I want the grid render without border so I set the css `border: none;`

But there is a problem. The grid still show a underline when I selected a row or over it. How to clear the underline? Thanks.

[Sample Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11s2)

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-rowLines

Comment: Thank you Evan! You really helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`rowLines`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-rowLines):

> False to remove row line styling

For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11s7